# Probability of at least 1 of 5 basketball players of hitting the basket provided that all players have 2 shots each.

Tags: probability

The following probability problem came to my mind while I was chatting with some of my friends:

> There are five basketball players, all have the same skills. Each player is given two balls and is asked to hit a basket from a specified point in the court (the same for each player). What's the probability of at least one of the five players to hit the basket?

I would say that the answer is a probability of $1/2 = 0.5 = 50%$ , but there isn't solution. Is this the right solution?

The reasoning to tell me that $P(X) = 1/2$ where $X$ is the predicted outcome of one player hitting the basket is this:

Let $SN_n$ be a shot which didn't hit the basket and $SH_n$ be a shot which hit the basket. For each player, we have:

$$
PLAYER_1 = \{ SH_1, SN_1, SH_2, SN_2 \}\\
PLAYER_2 = \{ SH_1, SN_1, SH_2, SN_2 \}\\
PLAYER_3 = \{ SH_1, SN_1, SH_2, SN_2 \}\\
PLAYER_5 = \{ SH_1, SN_1, SH_2, SN_2 \}\\
$$

Therefore, 20 possible outcomes, each has a probability of $1/20$, but on the whole, if we count all the cases, those with $SH_n$ are 10. Therefore I would say that $10/20 = 1/2 = 0.5$ fraction of cases would lead to at least one player to hit the basket.

Is this the right way to think of such a simple problem?

Thanks for the attention!

**EDIT**: My assumptions were totally wrong, check out the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that each player has a probability $p$ of making the basket from the specificed spot. Then, the probability of (at least one shot made) is equal to $1-$(no shots made). The probability of a miss is $1-p$. Then we have 10 misses will occur with probability $(1-p)^{10}$. So our final answer is $1-\left(1-p\right)^{10}$.

What you have is a binomial distribution, since each player is virtually the same. You have $n=10$ and an unspecified $p$.

Comment: So, I guess my answer is incorrect. However, if $p = 1/2$, then the answer is $1 - (1 - 1/2)^{10} = 1 - (1/2)^{10} = 0.9990234375$ ? So high?

Comment: Indeed, if $p=1/2$ then the problem is equivalent to asking "What's the probability that I get at least one heads if I flip a coin 10 times"

Comment: The more the `times` (e.g. `n = 10000`), the more the probability will converge to `1`.

Comment: Anyway, shouldn't the answer be $1 - (1 - p)^{20}$ , as each player has 2 available shots?

Comment: There are only 5 players. 2 shots each, 5 players, is 10 shots right?

Comment: Forget it, I totally screwed it up ahahah . Of course is $10$ . Thank you!